# dotnet core api folder structure

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, design-patterns, directory-structure

im trying to start a new API. But there are a bunch of options that can be considered correct. I just wonder how everyone suggest doing it, or if there's an official way to do it that im ignoring.
This is going to be a N Layer architecture. With controllers / BLL classes / DAL layer. and some services to communicate with message queues and other services (which im extracting to different projects in the same solution) but my question would be for the main project how would you guys do the folders/namespaces. and naming of the classes in it. This is how im willing to approach, lemme know our thoughts:

```
apiproject
|
+> controllers/
|  + *Controller.cs (name of classes)
+> enumerables/
|  + *.cs (just a significant name)
+> handlers/
|  + I*Handler.cs (interfaces)
|  + implementors/
|  |  + *Handler.cs (implementations)
 +  Models/
|  +  *.cs (meaningfulName)
 +  DTO/
|  +  *.cs (meaningfulName)
 +  Validators/
|  +  *Validator.cs (DataAnnotations)
 +  Utils/
|  +  *Util.cs 
 +  Repositories/
|  +  I*Repository.cs 
|  + implementors/
|  |  + *Repository.cs (implementations)
|  + Entities/
|  |  *Entity.cs
+  Auth/
|  + MiddleWareStuff
```

I struggle mainly with the naming conventions, for instance is handler ok? how you guys organize your middlewares and action filters?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: [Northwind Traders](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/NorthwindTraders) is a good example of a clean, layered architecture. But IMHO there is no single answer, it all depends on your case, your needs, your knowledge, whether you're starting from scratch or continuing legacy code and a dozen of other factors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I just wonder how everyone suggest doing it, or if there's an official way to do it that I'm ignoring

There is no one right approach, there are ones that can work for you, your team and your project.

As for "official" guides - you can look into [Common web application architectures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures) guide from Microsoft. It mentions several popular options:

- [Traditional "N-Layer" architecture applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures#traditional-n-layer-architecture-applications)
- [Clean architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures#clean-architecture) (which I would argue is quite similar to  Hexagonal Architecture and Onion architecture which are based more or less on the same concept, but differs in terms and nuances)

There are multiple resources on those you can read about.

One more which is worth mentioning is [Vertical Slice Architecture](https://jimmybogard.com/vertical-slice-architecture/) ([video presentation](https://youtu.be/SUiWfhAhgQw)) which as far as I understand is quite similar to Feature Folders approach which personally I've grown fond over the last years (see [this](https://github.com/OdeToCode/AddFeatureFolders), [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/september/asp-net-core-feature-slices-for-asp-net-core-mvc) and [this](https://ardalis.com/api-feature-folders/))